# Is there a jQuery fix to make CSS3 work in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a jQuery solution to make all browsers behave like a browser with CSS3 capabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CSS Sandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/).